How do I remove a certificate from (RedHat) Linux ca-trust?
I installed a duplicate certificate for a CN in the ca-trust store of my RHEL8 systems (The 'Subject' field is the same, but the keys are different). I added the PEM file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors and ran update-ca-trust. This broke https validation.
How can I remove the certificate(s) that update-ca-trust installed? It seems that it only adds to the stores and doesn't delete.

This is less like a security question and more like a question about administrating your system. Please try [unix.se] instead or [serverfault.com]. In fact - there might also be answers there, see https://serverfault.com/questions/1025749/how-to-remove-a-root-ca-certificate

Thanks everybody, here's a recap.
update-ca-trust combines the low-priority sources under /usr/share/pki with the high-priority sources under /etc/pki/ca-trust/source.
Removing the PEM file from /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors and running update-ca-trust resolved the problem.
